# uml class diagram (an object of another class inside the class)

Tags: uml

if I use an object of another class in a class (as an attribute(?)), how can I show it in the uml diagram? should there be some connection between these classes or not?

Comment: I think you can find the answer in the following thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115418/how-to-depict-class-uses-class-relationship-via-uml

Comment: You draw a dependency to show the usage.